# How to remove required attribute if checked input in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" required>
<input type="text" ng-model="sec_name" required>

<h2>Check if you dont want enter full name</h2>

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="none">
```

How I can remove `required` attribute if user checked `input type="checkbox"`?
And to come back if unchecked?

It needs for `ng-disabled`:

```
<div ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Send form</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ng-required, instead of required, so you could set a model on the checkbox for example like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-required="!none">
<input type="text" ng-model="sec_name" ng-required="!none">

<h2>Check if you dont want enter full name</h2>

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="none">
```

Here is a working example for you - http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/16544/

Comment: It works because you have not `novalidate` attribute in form, but Angular JS does not work. Try to add `ng-disabled`

Comment: @Caur check the fiddle again, it does what you are asking it to do, including disabling the submit button. If this doesn't work when you implement it into your code, check that you have the correct form name. Also your send form button should be a button, not a div for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-required instead:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="sec_name" ng-required="none">
```

That's exactly why ng-required exists.